# Find the radical of${\langle x^2-y^2,x^4-x^2y^5\rangle}\subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, radicals

> Find the radical of $J:=\langle x^2-y^2,x^4-x^2y^5\rangle\subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

I would like to verify my answer please;

**Edit after comments:**

Excluding $(i,-1)$ from $V(J)$ and
$$\sqrt J=\langle (x-a)(y-b):(a,b)\in V(J)\rangle$$

---

One can calculate and observe $$V(J)=\{(0,0),(1,1,),(-1,1),(i,-1),(-i,-1)\}$$ According to the Nullstellensatz $$\sqrt J=I(V(J))\\=\langle (x-a)^i(y-b)^j:i,j\in\mathbb{N},(a,b)\in V(J)\rangle$$

Comment: If $(x-a)(y-b)$ is a genrator for your ideal, isn't $(x-a)^i(y-b)^j$ automatically contained in the ideal for any $i, j\in \Bbb N$? So the exponents are unnecessary? Also, $(i, -1)$ doesn't seem to be in the zero set of $x^2-y^2$.

Comment: @Servaes Why does Arthur comment still stand? His first point is that the exponents $i$ and $j$ are useless and I excluded them, and the second point is that $(i,-1)\notin V(J)$ and I excluded it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(a,b)\in V(J)$ then $a^2=b^2$ and hence also
$$0=a^4-a^2b^5=b^4-b^7=b^4(1-b^3),$$
so either $b=0$ or $b$ is a third root of unity, and hence with $\zeta\in\Bbb{C}$ a primitive third root of unity
$$V(J)\subset\{(0,0)\}\cup\{(\pm\zeta^k,\zeta^k)\},$$
and it is not hard to check that equality holds. Now the Nullstellensatz gives you $\sqrt{J}$.